# How can I address this issue? TypeError: __webpack_require__(...) is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, npm, webpack

I get this error message "TypeError: **webpack_require**(...) is not a function" at runtime, for some reason.

The full error stack is:

```
TypeError: __webpack_require__(...) is not a function
    at eval (rowsdisplaytable.tsx:25:1)
    at ./src/rowsdisplaytable.tsx (eval at append_javascript (main.min.js?v=a4e125c812cb3975203ae429a5b40d180b59b8e4602fcc78390ef4f0dd4d14ac3559189f65f23cd50fd971f98f5842b7746f4182babd20b7ca84e52314bcd4ac:59938:13), <anonymous>:872:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (eval at append_javascript (main.min.js?v=a4e125c812cb3975203ae429a5b40d180b59b8e4602fcc78390ef4f0dd4d14ac3559189f65f23cd50fd971f98f5842b7746f4182babd20b7ca84e52314bcd4ac:59938:13), <anonymous>:9178:42)
    at eval (component.tsx:18:75)
    at ./src/component.tsx (eval at append_javascript (main.min.js?v=a4e125c812cb3975203ae429a5b40d180b59b8e4602fcc78390ef4f0dd4d14ac3559189f65f23cd50fd971f98f5842b7746f4182babd20b7ca84e52314bcd4ac:59938:13), <anonymous>:641:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (eval at append_javascript (main.min.js?v=a4e125c812cb3975203ae429a5b40d180b59b8e4602fcc78390ef4f0dd4d14ac3559189f65f23cd50fd971f98f5842b7746f4182babd20b7ca84e52314bcd4ac:59938:13), <anonymous>:9178:42)
    at eval (hiplot_web.tsx:7:68)
    at ./src/hiplot_web.tsx (eval at append_javascript (main.min.js?v=a4e125c812cb3975203ae429a5b40d180b59b8e4602fcc78390ef4f0dd4d14ac3559189f65f23cd50fd971f98f5842b7746f4182babd20b7ca84e52314bcd4ac:59938:13), <anonymous>:751:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (eval at append_javascript (main.min.js?v=a4e125c812cb3975203ae429a5b40d180b59b8e4602fcc78390ef4f0dd4d14ac3559189f65f23cd50fd971f98f5842b7746f4182babd20b7ca84e52314bcd4ac:59938:13), <anonymous>:9178:42)
    at eval (eval at append_javascript (main.min.js?v=a4e125c812cb3975203ae429a5b40d180b59b8e4602fcc78390ef4f0dd4d14ac3559189f65f23cd50fd971f98f5842b7746f4182babd20b7ca84e52314bcd4ac:59938:13), <anonymous>:9288:37)
```

rowsdisplaytable.tsx where it occurs is:

```
var $ = require( 'jquery' );
require( 'datatables.net-bs4' )( window, $ ); ----- this is line 25 in the error message above
require( 'datatables.net-colreorder' )( window, $ );
require( 'datatables.net-colreorder-bs4' )( window, $ );
require( 'datatables.net-buttons' )( window, $ );
require( 'datatables.net-buttons-bs4' )( window, $ );
```

If I click on the "component.tsx:18:75" line in the error stack, I see this:

```
var _rowsdisplaytable__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__ = __webpack_require__(/*! ./rowsdisplaytable */
"./src/rowsdisplaytable.tsx");
```

The relevant dependencies I have in package.json are:

```
"webpack": "5.72.1",
"webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^4.7.0",
"webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
```

Any assistance on this would be greatly appreciated. In order to install the build the project, I use the commands:

```
npm install --cache /tmp/empty-cache --legacy-peer-deps

npm run build-dev
```

I get no errors at install/build time, only at runtime.

I have tried modifying the package version for "webpack" in package.json, but they either caused failures at buildtime or resulted in the same error at runtime. I'm not sure what else I can do here. Thanks.